# Get Contents of previous table outside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below you find a piece of code. A container with two child div each containing a table. One is filled the other isn.'t. The [A] just above the second table should copy the contents of the first table into the second table.

```
<div class="example-code">
   <div class="content-box">
          <div class="content-box-wrapper">
                 <table id="carTable-20685519" data-car-id="20685519">
                        <tr><td>Dummy Data 1 <input type="text" name="car[20685519]"</td></tr>       
                 </table>
          </div>
   </div>
   <div class="content-box">
          <div class="content-box-wrapper">
                 <a id="copy-20685519">Copy from above table</a>
                 <table id="carTable-206823698" data-car-id="206823698">    
                 </table>
          </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've created some JQuery for that. However, it looks like prev() doesn't search out outside the current div.. How can I get this working?

```
<script>

$("a[id^='copy']").on('click', function () {

    console.log('Clicked');

    var id = $(this).next("table").attr('data-car-id'),
            previousId = $(this).prev('table').attr('data-car-id'),
    html = $(this).prev("table[id^='carTable-']").prop('innerHTML');

    $(this).next("table").html(html).find('input').each(function () {
        this.name = this.name.replace(previousId, id);
    });
});

</script>
```

[Demo in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90jtudd4/)

Comment: Have you tried: `html = $(this).parents('.exemple-code').find("table[id^='carTable-']").prop('innerHTML');`?

Comment: The `prev` and `next` functions look for 'borther' and 'sister' elements, not family relations. Technically, the tables are not directly related, the links arent't, they all share the same grandparent, but not parents, so `next()` and `prev()` don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("a[id^='copy']").on('click', function () {
    var previous = null;
    var tables = $('table');
    var index = tables.index($(this).next("table"));
    if (index > 0) {
        previous = $(tables[index-1])
    }
    $(this).next("table").html($(previous).html()).find('input').each(function () {
        this.name = this.name.replace(previousId, id);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/90jtudd4/1/

Answer (score 1):

They are in different branches. Use `closest` to search up then `find` to search down. Use `first()` to match the source table (which is the first of two tables in that grandparent div):

e.g.

```
$("a[id^='copy']").on('click', function () {

    console.log('Clicked');

    var $table = $(this).next("table");
    var id = $.attr('data-car-id'),
        previousId = $table.attr('data-car-id'),
    html = $table.closest('.example-code').find("table[id^='carTable-']").first().html();

    $table.html(html).find('input').each(function () {
        this.name = this.name.replace(previousId, id);
    });
});
```

Also, save the result of jQuery selectors, rather than requery over and over (much faster). e.g. `var $table`

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/90jtudd4/2/